# Can't instantiate abstract class clarifai2.dto.ClarifaiStatus

Tags: android, clarifai

Using Clarifai for Android getting error while invoking Clarifai

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke clarifai2.dto.ClarifaiStatus() with no args
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:94)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:859)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:832)
W/System.err:     at clarifai2.api.request.ClarifaiRequest$Impl.executeSync(ClarifaiRequest.java:249)
W/System.err:     at clarifai2.api.request.ClarifaiRequest$Builder.executeSync(ClarifaiRequest.java:170)
W/System.err:     at com.example.amutgeka.visualclarifia.MainActivity.train(MainActivity.java:120)
W/System.err:     at com.example.amutgeka.visualclarifia.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class clarifai2.dto.ClarifaiStatus
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
W/System.err:     at `enter code here`com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:91)
W/System.err:   ... 9 more
```

Comment: If i am not mistaken, Abstract class can never be instantiated. Read more [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java)

Comment: Abstract classes can't have instance, it can be extended to subclass and you can create instance of those subclasses.

Comment: Thank u fr rply, but my code doesn't contain any abstract class

Answer (score 1):

I maintain this library currently. The problem here is that `ClarifaiStatus` should not be instantiated directly (because it can't). If you look at the [source code for the library](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/clarifai2/dto/ClarifaiStatus.java#L20), you can see that we register a Gson adapter that defines how to construct a `ClarifaiStatus` (in this case, by calling the constructor for `AutoValue_ClarifaiStatus`, which is auto-generated code).

For some reason, that adapter doesn't seem to be getting picked up; if it were, `com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` wouldn't be getting invoked. So because no adapter is getting picked up, Gson falls back to its default behavior of trying to call the no-args constructor via reflection, which is impossible on an abstract class.

We haven't been able to reproduce this error, but we recently updated the client to support older versions of Gson, which might be the issue at hand. Can you make sure that you're using the latest version of the client, which is `2.2.3`? Let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks..I am using 2.2.1 will try with 2.2.3

Comment: Can you help me with the latest version I searched but I didn't find it